# Enviar parámetros a api con formGroup

Tags: angular, api, typescript, object

Tengo un formGroup que recojo los campos de la vista con formControlName así:

```
        this.editForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        dni: [''],
        name: [''],
        surname: [''],
        email: [''],
        city: [''],
        phone: [''],
        postal_code: [''],
    });
```

Y los envio asi a mi authService que es el que hace la petición a la api

```
    editProfile() {
    Swal.fire({
        title: '¿Estás seguro?',
        text: '¿Seguro que quieres modificar tu usuario?',
        type: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: 'Ok',
        cancelButtonColor: '#DD0031',
        confirmButtonColor: '#3F51B5',
    }).then((response) => {
        if (response.value) {
            return this.authService.editProfileUserAuth(this.editForm.value, this.user.id).subscribe(
                (response) => {
                    // @ts-ignore
                    this.toastr.success(response.message, 'Enhorabuena');
                },
                (error) => {
                    this.toastr.error(error, 'Error');
                }
            );
        }

    });
}
```

En mi authService tengo esto:

```
    editProfileUserAuth(userForm, id) {
    return this.http.put(
        `${routes.API_ENDPOINT_USER}/${id}`,
          {userForm}
    ).pipe(map(data => data));

}
```

El problema es que cuando hago la petición los parámetros se envían así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Hay alguna manera de enviarlos correctamente sin la propiedad userForm?
Ahora mismo no caigo.

Comment: Por favor, en vez de utilizar imágenes, inserta tu código en texto

Comment: Tu pregunta es un ejemplo de una pregunta bien formulada y con los datos necesarios para ser contestada, con la excepción de que has puesto capturas del código en lugar de pegarlo directamente. Puedes leer [Te he votado negativamente porque una captura del código no es de ayuda](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/) para una explicación sobre el tema. Sería bueno que, a pesar de haber recibido una respuesta, editaras tu pregunta para incluir el código. Un saludo

Comment: @Lucía tiene toda la razón. Yo soy daltónico y hay algunos colores que no veo bien en pantalla, por eso uso una configuración de colores determinada en mi editor de código. Al subir imágenes no dispongo de dicha configuración y no veo bien lo que publicas. Además subir fotos es mucho más difícil que copiapegar código. ¡ **PON CÓDIGO**, **NO PONGAS IMÁGENES** !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En tu authService tienes lo siguiente:

```
...
return this.http.put<User>(url, {userForm}).pipe(map(...));
```

Al pasar el parámetro con la sintaxis `{userForm}` lo que estás haciendo es equivalente a crear un objeto así:

```
 {userForm: userForm}
```

Por tanto la solución es sencilla: quita las llaves:

```
return this.http.put<User>(url, userForm).pipe(map(...));
```